# Game crashes when I assign a worker to his dream job

Tags: technical-issues, star-wars-tiny-death-star

Most of the times I try to put a worker to his dream job the game crashes, this doesn't happen every time. I have managed to get 1 worker to his dream job but the rest of them just makes the game crash.

I'm on a Nokia Lumia 620 running Windows Phone 8, there are many events that cause the game to crash but, at least for me, these crashes seem to be random, the only event that always causes the game to crash is assigning some workers to their dream jobs. It doesn't happen with all the workers, I have been able to assign some of them to their dream job, but some others just cause the game to crash. It is character dependant since when I try to assign the same character to its dream job, it crashes again.

Comment: His dream job was to develop the game further. However, he wasn't very good at it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Tiny Death Star has been [discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tiny_Death_Star):

> The game was removed from the Apple App Store and Google Play Store by Disney in October 2014.

If you are unable to workaround the bug/issue by restarting the application or your device, then there's nothing we can do: there is **no fix coming**.

If you are playing on iOS, I would not recommend uninstalling the game if you wish to keep it. Only those who had [previously downloaded the game on Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tiny_Death_Star#Bugs) can still redownload & access the game.

Answer (score -1):

Are you on iOS or Android?  There definitely seem to be some different bugs in the various versions.

I am on the iOS version, and while I haven't noticed it crashing for dream jobs there are a number of events that have caused the game to crash.  I've had better luck when I've forced most other apps to quit, and occasionally being in airplane mode seems to work better as well.  Good luck!

Comment: He's using Windows 8 Phone, in case you didn't read the second paragraph of the Opening Post (question).